# Using Brackets and XAMPP for PHP file, can't get Stylesheet to work?

Tags: php, stylesheet, adobe-brackets

Here's the code I have:

PHP Index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script> 

    <title>Our website</title>
</head>


<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}

ul#nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

ul#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

When I do Live Preview on Brackets, the stylesheet is not applied. However, when I begin to *edit* the stylesheet while Live Preview is on, the stylesheet will suddenly activate. But when I relaunch Live Preview, index.php will go back to looking like it has no stylesheet attached.

I have it set to launch as: http://localhost/WebsiteFolder/index.php/

The path for the index PHP is C:\xampp\htdocs\Website Folder\index.php

And the path for the css sheet is C:\xampp\htdocs\Website Folder\css\style.css

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's going wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Try to open in your network see if it has errors.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a bug in Brackets. It's had trouble updating on stylesheet changes since before this version, and they don't seem to have fixed it this time around.

Comment: @aldrin27 It doesn't work on the network ( http://localhost/WebsiteFolder/index.php/ ) It shows without style

Comment: Can you make a **SNIPPET** or **JSFIDDLE** ?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/paxfjra9/

So it seems the code should theoretically be fine. I don't know what's causing the disconnect.

Comment: I got it to work! :) I just needed to change the Live Preview Base URL in Adobe-Brackets Project Settings. I changed it from http://localhost/WebsiteFolder/index.php/ to simply http://localhost/WebsiteFolder/ =) Yay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work! :) I just needed to change the Live Preview Base URL in Adobe-Brackets Project Settings. I changed it from localhost/WebsiteFolder/index.php to simply localhost/WebsiteFolder =) Yay